# File Upload gives Bad Request in Django using modelform

Tags: django, file-upload, django-forms

I am trying to upload a file using a model form but form.save() is giving me bad request.
This is my model:

```
class cv(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField('Name', max_length=64, null=True)
    path_to_cv = models.FileField('CV', upload_to='/', null=True)
```

Here is the form:

```
class Step2(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
    model = cv
```

Here is the view:

```
def phdStep2(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = PhdStep2(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/step/3/')
    else:
        form = PhdStep2()
    return render(request, 'step2.html', {'form': form})
```

Here is the template for form:

```
<form action="/step/2" method="post" class="well form" role="form" enctype="multipart/form-data">
{% csrf_token %}
{% bootstrap_form form %}
{% buttons %}
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">
        Submit
    </button>
{% endbuttons %}
</form>
```

Here is the media_root in settings.py:

```
MEDIA_ROOT = '/home/supertux/PyCharm/myproject/admissions/media'
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
```

I have read like 10s of such threads and find that most times problem was enctype in form which i already incorporated. Now as i understand, this should upload the file since its a model form, but i always get a 400 Bad Request. I want to store the name and path to the file in database. What am i doing wrong?

Comment: Can you post the full stack trace you're receiving?

Comment: The problem is i am getting a 400 Bad Request which means it doesn't show any trace (just a big Bad Request (400) even with Debug set to true), or i don't how to get the trace when 400 occurs. So what do i do now?

Comment: Try replacing `upload_to='/'` with `upload_to='%Y/%m/%d'` and make sure that the user running your django application has write permissions to `MEDIA_ROOT`. If neither of these suggestions help you can turn on some [additional logging](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/topics/logging/#configuring-logging) to hopefully reveal what the issue is.

Comment: well changing upload_to worked. Thanks Man. If you please post it as an answer, i will accept it. However, What if I want to upload to media_root folder and not in a subfolder?  '/' doesn't work and neither does ''.

Comment: Scott Woodal's answer helped me find my similar issue: `upload_to` should **not** start with a slash. If you want to pile up the `MEDIA_ROOT` dir, and not use subdirectories, you can do `upload_to='./'`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try replacing `upload_to='/'` with `upload_to='%Y/%m/%d'` and make sure that the user running your django application has write permissions to `MEDIA_ROOT`. If neither of these suggestions help you can turn on some additional logging to hopefully reveal what the issue is.

Update:
I'd recommended that you set `upload_to` to something so you don't have 100's if not 1000's of files pile up in the same directory. It will be come hard to manage over time. I haven't tried this but what if you set it to `upload_to=''`, will it accept that? In Django 1.6 they made this parameter optional.

Update2: I was incorrect about what version this was made optional. I was reading the development version of the docs. Apologies.

Comment: if i set upload_to='', i get `django.core.management.base.CommandError: One or more models did not validate:
admissions.cv: "path": FileFields require an "upload_to" attribute.` I am on django 1.6.1

Answer (score 1):

**Try to catch an Exception if you don't know what's going on**.

The point is:

> django FileField try to explain file path with .*  to an **relative** 
>   path but /* to an
>   **absolute** path

It would be SuspiciousFileOperation exception located in       django.core.files.storage module which seems a magic here,

```
def path(self, name):
try:
    path = safe_join(self.location, name)
except ValueError:
    raise SuspiciousFileOperation("Attempted access to '%s' denied." % name)
return os.path.normpath(path)
```

Answer (score -2):

When `upload_to=""` doesn't work, try `upload_to="."`. Path "." is default path MEDIA_ROOT (in Django 1.6.x)